# How read image via fileReader and PUT it to CouchDB by jquery $.ajax method?

Tags: jquery, ajax, couchdb, filereader

html:

```
 <input type="file" v-model="fileName" @change="fileNameChange" />
```

javascript:

```
 fileNameChange(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0]
        console.log('this.fileName', file)
    let reader = new FileReader()

    reader.onload = (e) => {
    let path = `db/${this.doc._id}/${file.name}?rev=${this.doc._rev}`
    console.log('imgdata', e, e.target.result, reader.result)
    $.ajax(path, {
                type: 'PUT', 
                contentType: file.type,
                data: reader.result, //e.target.result,
                processData: true,
                success(resp) { 
                    console.log(resp)
                    utils.notify('file is uploaded succesfully')
                },
                error(err) { console.log(err) },
            })
   };

   reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)
 }
```

this code working, I see 'file is uploaded succesfully' message, but in CouchDB document I see 0 bytes length attachment:

```
 1.jpg  0 bytes, image/jpeg
```

how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found solution. If change one string from

```
 processData: true,
```

to

```
 processData: false,
```

all working good